# How to use regular MFC dll explicitly linked to client app

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I'm writing an MFC regural dll with statically linked MFC, inside which I use some MFC DAO classes. I need to link it to client app at the run time. Everything goes well untill I call FreeLibrary() function. I get an assertion in module appcore in this place

```
if (m_lpfnDaoTerm != NULL)
{
    // If a DLL, YOU must call AfxDaoTerm prior to ExitInstance
    ASSERT(!afxContextIsDLL);
    (*m_lpfnDaoTerm)();
}
```

Any suggestions why does it appear? 
Are there some features when explicitly linking MFC dlls?

Comment: Did you try to follow the comment before assertion?

Comment: Oh thanx, I must be more attentive.